# I think I'm calculating the total revenue from each warehouse wrong

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've got a question I'm working through and I'd like someone to double check my code because I'm trying to calculate the revenue for each warehouse in a database and the returning values seem high - it's returning tens of millions for most warehouses. Not impossibly high but high enough for me to take a second look.

[Here is the ER diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rn4u.png)
[image]

And here is my code:

```
SELECT WAREHOUSES.WAREHOUSE_ID, WAREHOUSES.WAREHOUSE_NAME, SUM(ORDER_ITEMS.QUANTITY * 
PRODUCTS.LIST_PRICE) AS TOTAL
FROM WAREHOUSES
JOIN INVENTORIES ON INVENTORIES.WAREHOUSE_ID = WAREHOUSES.WAREHOUSE_ID
JOIN PRODUCTS ON PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_ID = INVENTORIES.PRODUCT_ID 
JOIN ORDER_ITEMS ON PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_ID = ORDER_ITEMS.PRODUCT_ID
GROUP BY WAREHOUSES.WAREHOUSE_NAME, WAREHOUSES.WAREHOUSE_ID
ORDER BY TOTAL DESC;
```

Is there something wrong with my SUM? I'm new to SQL so I'm sure you'll find plenty of tweaks to this code - and I'd love to hear about it!

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "revenue" here?  Revenue would normally mean the sum of the value of all goods sold in which case you'd almost certainly need to include the `orders` table and doesn't obviously make sense to group by warehouse since I don't see a way to determine which warehouse supplied which items on a historical order.  If you're grouping by warehouse, I'd guess that you'd really be looking for the inventory value by warehouse in which case joining to `order_items` is probably incorrect.  There is a `standard_cost` and a `list_price` on the `product` table already.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be helpful, preferably pared down to a manageable example.

Answer (score 2):

You are calculating the total sales over all time for each product inside a warehouse.  And then adding them up at the warehouse level.

I do not see that this is useful.  And it is definitely overcounting sales.

I don't know what "revenue" means at the warehouse level.  The data model doesn't seem to have any indication of which warehouse provided the products for a given order.

My best guess is that "revenue" means "potential revenue".  That is, for all the products in inventory in the warehouse, how much revenue could be generated if they were sold at full price?

As a hint:  This calculation has nothing to do with orders or orderlines.  It only requires calculations between products and inventory.

Answer (score 0):

The query looks OK, except I would think `order_items.unit_price` reflects the actual price paid and hence the sales revenue.

Here it is tidied up a little. I use aliases for the table names rather than repeating the whole name. Opinions vary on how to lay out SQL, and join clauses in particular, but this works better for me than a monolithic block of uppercase text.

```
select w.warehouse_id
     , w.warehouse_name
     , sum(oi.quantity * oi.unit_price) as total
from   warehouses w
       join inventories i on i.warehouse_id = w.warehouse_id
       join products p on p.product_id = i.product_id
       join order_items oi on p.product_id = oi.product_id
group by w.warehouse_name, w.warehouse_id
order  by total desc;
```

You could check the results for one order, or one product, or one warehouse by including their ID in the `select` list and `group by` clauses and confirming that it gives the expected total. Sample data would help here.